# Trying to pipe an image to ssh stdin input

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

So what I'm trying to do was to displaying image on remote server, and moving them- I have think a way to achieve this with `wmctrl` and ImageMagick's `display`, so I wrote a simple command.

```
cat "$img" | ssh "beer@laika" "export DISPLAY=:0; display - & sleep 5 && wmctrl -r ImageMagick -e 0,254,600,800,560"
```

Where `$img` is the a variable that takes `png`, `jpeg`, and `jpg` file as an input— the problem is above method doesn't seem to be working, the error is.

```
display: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
```

It seems `display` didn't accept the input properly, I think some process had absorb the stdin.

I tried debugging the command, and found out if the command that takes place after `display -` get removed— it works ! the image would be displayed on my remote server.

```
cat "$img" | ssh "beer@laika" "export DISPLAY=:0; display -"
```

<sup>↑↑ Worked ↑↑</sup>

If I manually move the window through ssh, it would ran successfully without any problem.

```
ssh beer@laika "export DISPLAY=:0; wmctrl -r ImageMagick -e 0,254,600,750,480"
```

<sup>↑↑ Worked ↑↑</sup>

What could be the problem ? Anyone can shed some light for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the standard input.

A way of solving it is to transfer the file first (the `cat > filename`), and then run the commands, so your command line would be, for example:

```
cat "$img" | ssh beer@laika "export DISPLAY=:0; cat > /tmp/temporary_image;display /tmp/temporary_image &  sleep 5;wmctrl -r ImageMagick -e 0,254,600,750,480"
```

Comment: Pressing C at the `display` GUI window is sent as an X11 event -- it's not the same as sending it via stdin.

Comment: @user1686 the problem is `display` and stdin, that's the point and the solution works. But you're right so I removed the reference to the `C` key in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, it really useful

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send stdin to a background job, generally. If the process is started with `&` then the shell will actually redirect its stdin from /dev/null to avoid any read attempts.

(And the process it was started normally from an interactive terminal but Ctrl+Z'd and 'bg'd later, it would receive a SIGTTIN whenever it tried to read from the terminal.)

So you'll need either to first receive the image into a temporary file, or to replace the `&` usage with a custom tool. For example, use the 'subprocess' module in Python, or Open3() in Ruby – they give you much more control over which FDs to pass.

It might be possible to do it from within the shell itself, as explicit redirections override this:

```
display - < /dev/stdin &
```

Actually, it would be best to specify the position up front and avoid the delayed move. Most X11 programs traditionally accept the `-geometry` option, so check if this works:

```
display -geometry "WIDTHxHEIGHT+XOFFSET+YOFFSET" -
```

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know that option exist, gonna test it tomorrow in my office.

Comment: I started a question on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202860/cannot-sent-stdin-to-background-job) and raised a bounty  there.